# How to implement azure push notifications in ionic 2 for iOS. (Closed)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I tried  all possible  way but not able to implement  azure push notifications  in ionic 2 .
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: too broad and you haven't provided any info on what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This link shows how to plug everything.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-push

And instead of use the phone gap version, you can install the Ionic Native version of that plugin.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/

Note: It's better if you post the code of what have you tried so we can give you a specific answer.